# Get and display many2one line ids record

Tags: odoo-14

I have model structure as

```
class VendorEvaluationTemplate(models.Model):
    _name = 'vendor.evaluation.template'
    _description = 'Vendor Evaluation Template'

    name = fields.Char(string='Name', required=True)
    evaluation_lines = fields.One2many('vendor.evaluation.template.line', 'evaluation_template_id', string='Vendor Evaluation Template Line')

class VendorEvaluationTemplateLine(models.Model):
    _name = 'vendor.evaluation.template.line'
    _description = 'Details Vendor Evaluation Template'

    evaluation_template_id = fields.Many2one('vendor.evaluation.template', string='Evaluation Template', ondelete="cascade")
    name = fields.Char(string='Name', required=True)

class VendorEvaluation(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'vendor.evaluation'

     evaluation_template = fields.Many2one('vendor.evaluation.template', string='Evaluation Template')
```

Now the requirement is when i select evaluation_template, the related lines name from vendor.evaluation.template.line should display below this field.

Answer (score 0):

Following code will work if you only want to display related lines for information purposes. Ref [related fields](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/developer/reference/addons/orm.html#reference-fields-related)

```
evaluation_template_lines = fields.One2many(
    related='evaluation_template.evaluation_lines',
    string="Vendor Evaluation Template Line"
)
```